# How to get VPN user through Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vpn

My scenario is: I have a server in the main office (where few users work) and the majority of the users are in remote locations, and they connect to this server through VPN.  In the remote locations the computer have its own name and user, and then the user connects to VPN to get access to main office's server.

I am using excel to send some information to a database in the main office's server and I need to achieve 2 things through VBA Excel:

1.- Know if the remote user is connected to the VPN or not. 
2.- If is connected which is the VPN user that is logged in.

I have been researching a lot all the articles related to this, but the functions explained in the articles, returned me the PC Name or the user name in the PC, not the VPN user. I need to get the 2 points that I explained before. How I could do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exact answer and i couldn't find useful solution in VBA, but [this VB code](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1054354) might help you. But i need to warn you, this solution is proper only for MS VPN connections and won't work with Cisco ones.

For Cisco VPN - check: [AnyConnect VPN Client API](http://software.cisco.com/download/release.html?mdfid=283000185&flowid=17001&softwareid=282364313&release=3.0.3054&relind=AVAILABLE&rellifecycle=&reltype=latest). with few examples in C++ and full documentation.

See similar question too:

[Find and start a VPN connection in VB .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349729/find-and-start-a-vpn-connection-in-vb-net)

[VBscript VPN (PPP adapter) IP address](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/13b13faf-9c4e-4283-9d8b-5710b4b000bc/vbscript-vpn-ppp-adapter-ip-address?forum=ITCG)

[VBS script using WMI objects to get IP address of VPN PPTP connection](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/ef4cdbe8-84b7-4e58-945c-371812c53513/vbs-script-using-wmi-objects-to-get-ip-address-of-vpn-pptp-connection?forum=ITCG)

Comment: It works to know if I am connected to the VPN. The requirement of knowing the user I resolved using a trusted connection to connect VBA with SQL and putting CURRENT_USER to track the user that create / update a record in the database. Thanks.